# Screen flickers after installing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, nouveau, flicker

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 11 using Dual Boot on a Lenovo computer and when I log in the screen flickers, not being able to interact well with the OS.

The equipment has the following specifications: CPU: Intel i7-11370H 3.3GHz RAM: 16GB GPU: MX450 Display: 16.0" WQXGA Intel iRIS-xe. In Software & Updates I have checked the option: Using X.Org X server-Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source).

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to remove the screen flickering by installing the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers. Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics driver to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies. Don't uninstall the open source Nouveau graphics drivers. Leave them installed as a fallback option in case Ubuntu ever has problems booting.

Comment: The suggestion, given in many other places, to add to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT the value "i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2" failed to solve the problem for me.  What worked was to install appropriate graphics drivers as suggested here.  Thanks.  
My setup, if it's helpful to anyone else:  
Ubuntu 22.04.3  
Kernel 6.2.0.33-generic  
CPU Intel i7-10700F (16) @ 4.8GHz  
GPU NVIDIA GeForce GT 730

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about your hardware it's difficult to say, however the first port of call for graphics issues is to ensure there are no additional drivers available - including proprietary ones, which unfortunately are often a necessary evil.

Assuming you have already checked for driver updates using the "Software Updater" application, check the "Additional Drivers" application to see if there are any recommended.

If none are showing, ensure that "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" option is enabled then check again.

In summary:

- Open the "Software Updater" application to check for updates
- If none found or you still have the issue, then;
- Open the "Software & Updates" application, go to the "Ubuntu Software" tab
- Enable the "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" option
- Run the "Additional Drivers" application to check for any applicable drivers

Failing all that you might need to seek more specific advice by searching for information related to your specific model of laptop.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.
The equipment has the following characteristics:
CPU: Intel i7-11370H 3.3GHz
RAM: 16GB
GPU: MX450
Display: 16.0" WQXGA
Intel iRIS-xe

In "Software and updates" I have checked the option:
Using X.Org X server-Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)